# How to Start Dictation programmatically?

Tags: macos, swift, dictation

I want to add the microphone icon into my app and start dictation with it. Is there a way to start dictation programmatically in Swift?? Except as to parse Edit menu and get the proper menu item?

I made this workaround and it works but...:

```
@IBAction func startDictation(sender: AnyObject) {
    if wordInputField.acceptsFirstResponder {
        self.makeFirstResponder(wordInputField)
    }

    if let menuItem = dictationMenuItem("startDictation:") {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0, target: menuItem.target!, selector: menuItem.action, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

func dictationMenuItem(selectorName : String) -> NSMenuItem? {
    var edit = NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu?.itemWithTitle("Edit")
    if let count = edit?.submenu?.numberOfItems {
        let lastItem = edit?.submenu?.itemAtIndex(count - 2)
        if lastItem?.action == NSSelectorFromString(selectorName) {
            return edit?.submenu?.itemAtIndex(count - 2)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: *"it works but..."* ...but what? If it works, what are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

I think you need to start the SpeechRecognitionServer...

```
osascript -e 'tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
   set theResponse to listen for {"yes", "no"} with prompt "Hello. Do you like me?"
   if theResponse is "yes" then
       say "I like you, too."
   else
       say "Am I bovvered?"
   end if
end tell'
```

**Original Answer**

You can start dictation from Applescript, and you can start Applescript from Swift, so there is a roundabout way of getting there that might keep you going till someone cleverer than me works out the *"proper"* way :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift

import Foundation

let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
task.arguments = ["-e","tell app \"System Events\" to key code {63,63}"]

task.launch()
```

It is tantamount to pressing the `fn` key twice on the keyboard - keycode 63.

Comment: but it wont work if user has changed this fnfn hotkey

Comment: That is true.... pesky users! Always causing trouble :-)

Comment: Thanks Mark. But it is not exactly what I need. I can create NSSpeechRecognizer and detect commands. But I'm developing an translation app so I want to use dictation to translate unknown words.